# SVG - привести текст в path

Tags: html5, svg, inkscape

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал текст, выделил 2 первые буквы. Выбрал контур -> оконтурить объект
На выходе получается для каждой буквы создается path, а сделать так чтобы один path для 2 и более символов.

Собственно какова последовательность действий?

Comment: Разгруппировать, выделить всё и Контур→Сумма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить один `path` для нескольких букв, можно воспользоваться онлайн инструментом - [***Google Font to Svg Path***](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не включенный чекбокс `Separate Characters:` сгенерирует один path для двух символов **"Te"**

```html
<svg width="56.95" height="37.925" viewBox="0 0 56.95 37.925" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.25mm" fill="black" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:0.25mm;fill:black">
<path d="M 15.375 37.5 L 10.625 37.5 L 10.625 4 L 0 4 L 0 0 L 25.875 0 L 25.875 4 L 15.375 4 L 15.375 37.5 Z M 52.375 31.6 L 55.1 34.275 Q 54.325 35.075 53.4 35.75 A 10.498 10.498 0 0 1 51.628 36.788 A 11.757 11.757 0 0 1 51.35 36.913 A 11.203 11.203 0 0 1 49.731 37.466 A 13.549 13.549 0 0 1 48.862 37.662 Q 47.5 37.925 45.825 37.925 A 15.846 15.846 0 0 1 43.088 37.7 Q 41.452 37.413 40.096 36.76 A 9.955 9.955 0 0 1 40.075 36.75 A 11.626 11.626 0 0 1 36.86 34.482 A 10.881 10.881 0 0 1 36.075 33.6 Q 34.5 31.625 33.75 29.075 Q 33 26.525 33 23.75 Q 33 21.975 33.363 20.238 Q 33.725 18.5 34.413 16.925 Q 35.1 15.35 36.138 14 Q 37.175 12.65 38.538 11.675 Q 39.9 10.7 41.563 10.138 A 10.715 10.715 0 0 1 44.084 9.622 A 12.978 12.978 0 0 1 45.2 9.575 Q 47.9 9.575 50.075 10.45 A 10.811 10.811 0 0 1 53.024 12.2 A 10.041 10.041 0 0 1 53.775 12.9 A 10.615 10.615 0 0 1 55.908 16.144 A 12.352 12.352 0 0 1 56.125 16.687 A 13.147 13.147 0 0 1 56.885 20.094 A 15.92 15.92 0 0 1 56.95 21.55 Q 56.95 22.325 56.9 23.25 A 27.799 27.799 0 0 1 56.808 24.475 A 23.6 23.6 0 0 1 56.75 25 L 37.75 25 A 10.838 10.838 0 0 0 38.008 27.403 A 9.427 9.427 0 0 0 38.35 28.562 Q 38.95 30.2 39.988 31.388 Q 41.025 32.575 42.438 33.25 A 7.005 7.005 0 0 0 45.474 33.925 A 8.053 8.053 0 0 0 45.5 33.925 A 18.253 18.253 0 0 0 46.635 33.892 Q 47.22 33.855 47.727 33.779 A 9.23 9.23 0 0 0 48.238 33.687 Q 49.164 33.494 49.858 33.226 A 6.623 6.623 0 0 0 50.162 33.1 Q 50.95 32.75 51.475 32.35 A 14.626 14.626 0 0 0 51.906 32.01 Q 52.164 31.797 52.375 31.6 Z M 41.375 21.25 L 52.55 21.25 L 52.55 20.15 A 6.302 6.302 0 0 0 52.259 18.218 A 5.785 5.785 0 0 0 51.987 17.525 Q 51.425 16.325 50.463 15.438 Q 49.5 14.55 48.238 14.05 Q 46.975 13.55 45.575 13.55 A 8.839 8.839 0 0 0 44.107 13.666 A 6.491 6.491 0 0 0 42.638 14.087 A 7.878 7.878 0 0 0 41.201 14.877 A 6.719 6.719 0 0 0 40.475 15.462 A 7.521 7.521 0 0 0 39.282 16.87 A 6.834 6.834 0 0 0 39.025 17.3 A 10.42 10.42 0 0 0 38.552 18.271 A 7.701 7.701 0 0 0 38.225 19.2 L 36.75 22.05 L 41.375 21.25 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</g>
</svg>
```